# load page with focus on a ul field (jquerymobile)

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, html-lists

I want to load this page, with the focus on the ul...
autocomplete works great!I just want it to display with the focus on the
input field (which is a ul).
is there some javascript to get this to work?

```
<ul id="autocomplete"
  data-role="listview"
  data-inset="true"
  data-filter="true"
  data-filter-placeholder="Find a item number..."
  data-filter-theme="d">
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I am looking to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").focus();
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: `.ready()` shouldn't be used in jQuery Mobile. JQM uses different event than jQuery.

Comment: Omar, what event to I test for?

Comment: here is the event JQM should test for per http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/api/events.html:  $('#itemlookuppage').live('pagecreate',function(event){        however, this didn't help either...

Answer (score 0):

Use pageshow event, like this (live is deprecated in JQuery 1.7, instead on() should be used):

```
$(document).on("#pageid", "pageshow", function () {
    $("#autocomplete").focus();
});
```

`pagecreate` fires once before the page is displayed, therefore it does not work, just like `pageinit` does not either.